# dompdf using spot colors

Tags: pdf-generation, dompdf, pantone

Is it possible to use spot colors(like Pantone) in dompdf?

In TCPDF one can easily define(`'white'   => array(  0,   0,   0,   0, 'White')`) and use(`TCPDF_COLORS::$spotcolor['white']`) spot colors , but the HTML rendering of dompdf is better.

Answer (score 0):

dompdf does not support spot colors directly. It does, however, support using CMYK to define a color in CSS, e.g.

```
.white { color: cmyk(0,0,0,0); }
```

This does not mean, however, that a PDF will necessarily accurately represent the color across mediums (e.g. screen, print) because dompdf does not currently support color space profiles such as ICC.